# How to get inner child values Firebase?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve the inner child values by comparing the node with my string array. I have the following database structure in Firebase.

**structure:**

```
-Posts
    -uid1
        -postid1
            -postid1:
            -title:
            -description:
        -postid2
            -postid2:
            -title:
            -description:
    -uid2
        -postid1
            -postid1:
            -title:
            -description:
```

I want to get all postid's data by comparing their uid's from given String array. How do I get postid, title,description of every Node from inside uid > postid > postid,title,description?

Following is my id's that I want to compare with Firebase `uids` to get only those post's data.

```
String uids[]={"uid1","uid2"};
```

How can I write the solution in Android Java Code?

I have written something like this.

```
final String uids[]={"id1","id2"};
        DatabaseReference reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    for(int i=0;i< uids.length;i++)
                        if(uids[i].equals(ds.getKey()))
                        {
                            // stuck in here
                        }
                }
            }
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });
```

I am stuck with the code where the UIDis get matched. How do I get inner postid data?

Comment: Could you show us what code you have at present? Seeing what you have tried may well guide their answers.

Comment: Yes, please check the updated answer. i am not able to write the code to get postid data. please help me to complete the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem using a recursive method. First, you need to transform that array to a List like this:

```
String[] uids = {"uid1", "uid2"};
List<String> uidList = Arrays.asList(uids);
```

Make the `uidList` a global variable:

```
private List<String> uidList;
```

And change the above line to only:

```
uidList = Arrays.asList(uids);
```

Now, define a reference:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference postsRef = rootRef.child("Posts");
```

And create a new list of `Post` objects:

```
List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here is the method that does the magic:

```
public void getAllUserPosts() {
    if (uidList.size() > 0) {
        String uid = uidList.get(0);
        uidList.remove(0);
        postsRef.child(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Post post = ds.getValue(Post.class);
                    posts.add(post);
                }
                getAllUserPosts();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }
        });
    }
}
```

In the end, simply call this method:

```
getAllUserPosts();
```

The result will be a list full with all Post objects of all users.

Comment: Difficult solution. I am not able to understand. Please make it simpler

Comment: What do you not understand? It cannot be simpler than that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61981810/how-to-get-nested-root-names-for-present-value-firebase

Comment: I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.

Comment: Sure. upvote to my question = i will accept your answer.